# Why does the amount a css value is changed by effect performance?

Tags: javascript, html, css, parallax

I have a web page and am trying to implement some parallax scrolling effects.

If I change the "top" value of a div by 0.3 * the scroll position the movement looks buttery smooth but when it is 0.7 or higher * the scroll position it becomes very janky on Firefox and janky for a while on Chrome and then smooth after.

Eg.

This looks terrible:

```
var imageOffset = lastScrollY * 0.9;         
$image.css({top: `${imageOffset}px`});
```

This looks great:

```
var imageOffset = lastScrollY * 0.3;         
$image.css({top: `${imageOffset}px`});
```

Comment: Side note reference: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/

Comment: Yep I've been through that, might be worth adding that in the dev tools timeline most of the time for each frame is spent in idle